# Hide folders in samba

Tags: samba, centos5

I have a samba server running on CentOS 5.6.

When I browse the the server from Windows 7 computer I see a share that I did not assign.

[image]

I have already looked through the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` there was no share in the file that was uncommented by that name.

Where is it coming from, can I get rid of it, or atleast hide it.

The share is the home dir of the unprivileged user for the server

**I can / will post my smb.conf if needed.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an automatic share created by the `[homes]` section in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`. Just comment out the `[homes]` section and its options then restart Samba.  You may also be interested in leaving the share enabled and configuring it as `browseable = no` instead.

Have a look at [`man smb.conf`](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/smb.conf.5.html) for more details.